# Swift do try catch error

Tags: swift, xcode6

i am having problem with swift do try catch

my xCode doesn't recognize try or catch
gives me error like  this.did some googling and watched some tutorials.they do the same as i did but i get this error.using xCode 6.3
need help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GiPe.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5bZ6.png

Comment: Please include the code you're attempting, and the *exact* error it is generating.

Comment: Try/catch was introduced with Swift 2/Xcode 7. It won't compile in your (stone-old :) Xcode 6.3

Comment: please don't link to images when asking questions, make everyone life easier by posting the code instead. Please read [ask]

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anishparajuli555/e3f7e851ef91042ae7aa look at this gist ...

Answer (score 3):

The error-handling model using `throw/try/catch` is one of the major
new features that came with **Swift 2** and Xcode 7.
You cannot compile that code with Xcode 6.3 (Swift 1.2).

The current Xcode version (at the time of writing this) is Xcode 7.2,
so for any Swift development it is recommended that you upgrade.
(If necessary for other reasons, you can install older Xcode versions in parallel.)